# can't bring https protocol to running

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, https, wordpress, iis-8.5

I have a wordpress website, hosted on Windows Server 2012. **http is working, but https is not!**

- I got a SSL certificate from the provider (via digicert), and installed in into the Certificate Store in "Personal"
- In IIS, on the website, I chose "Edit Bindings" and entered https protocol for the IP on port 443. And I selected the SSL Certificate.
- Port 443 is definitively open (checked firewall settings)

But when I want to access the website from a client computer via https, I always get a timeout.

Any ideas?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue. If it is not the firewall of the machine itself, it can be a firewall by your hosting provider (or anywhere else between your server and your local machine).

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef Like the other comment said, you neglected the fact that your server is not directly connected to.

Comment: Thank you. I came nearer and posted a new question. SSL is working because it works when calling the website from inside. Firewall also seems to be correct. And provider says, they are not blocking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Actually the provider was blocking from outside. It turned out the support guy has given me a wrong answer in the first place.